# SPSS - calculate new variable from two string using if-then

Tags: if-statement, spss

I need to develop a statement that will pull string values from two col based on their values and missing values. For example.

- COL-A, COL-B, NEW_VAR
- AA, BB, **AA**
- ___, CC, **CC**
- DD, __, **DD**
- __, __, __

I know this is a simple statement, but I can't seem to figure it out today.

Comment: do you mean missing values or empty values?

Comment: Empty values. I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should do it:

```
string new_var(a20).
if (COL_A<>"" and COL_B<>"") or COL_B="" new_var=COL_A.
if new_var="" and COL_B<>"" new_var=COL_B.
```